# Ability to 'like' blog posts in WordPress: Does this sort of feature need a custom database table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, database-design

I'm about to build 'like blog posts' functionality into my WordPress website.

The idea is to put a button on each blog post so that users can 'like' it. I plan to set up a custom page which will display a list of 'liked' posts for the current logged-in user.

**My question:** Would this functionality need a new database table? Or should I use both user and post meta to accomplish this? Please keep in mind scalability when answering. I need to make sure the feature can handle 1,000s of users and posts.

Answer (score 0):

Use [ZillaLikes](http://www.themezilla.com/plugins/zillalikes/)
This does everything you require already in a plugin :)

If you wanted to do it yourself... I would use an additional table if you wanted to relate these likes to Users or IPs. If you just want a figure then I would have it as Meta data for the post which +1 each time. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I need to code something myself as I'm integrating it with functionality elsewhere on my site.

Comment: Have amended answer for you.

Comment: I'm planning to relate users to their likes. Just took at look at the ZillaLikes plugin you suggested - I noticed it doesn't relate users to their likes. So it simply uses post meta to add to or subtract from the like count. If I went down the post and user meta route - would there be any performance issues after 1,000s of users have liked 1,000s of posts? I can see the meta value fields getting pretty heavy. Would using a custom table improve performance?

Comment: Nah 1000 is nothing in grand swing of things. I would just have a table with userID, PostID ensuring that two entries together make it unique. Then just sum all the same for a single PostID. In theory you could do millions this way in a single table. This is also really quick / easy for SQL to compute. Onwards from that you could add resources, then caching _IF_ you had problems, which with 1000 you really really shouldn't.

Comment: I actually mean't 1,000(s) as in I need it to scale if it gets big. But yeah, I'm thinking the table is the right way to go!

Comment: Yeah this really will be fine, having 1000(s) of entries in a single table will be kids stuff for SQL.

Comment: I know the table can handle it... I was thinking 1,000s with regards to post meta and user meta. With a custom table, each like event will take up one row. So 1,000s of rows. No problem there! But with user meta and post meta, everything will be saved in a single row. Take the post meta table - the meta key would be let's say 'post_liked' and the meta value would be an associative array that could potentially have 1,000s of key value pairs. Therefore I'm thinking that single row in the post meta table could get bloated!

Answer (score 0):

If you use an extra table it would be much harder to get the likes count but on the other side it would be much easier to set the people who liked it. I would still suggest using an extra table.

Answer (score 0):

I would have another table:

```
 likes
    post_id   user_id
    5         2873  
    19        238
    223       98
    5         15
```

post_id is a foreign key to the likes table and user ID likewise. 
This way you can keep track of what users liked which posts and users can like more than one post.

You could then use a nice query to return how many likes each post has

```
SELECT user_id,COUNT(*) as count FROM likes GROUP BY post_id ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Would return something like:

```
post_id   count
5         2
19        1
223       1
```

I think, don't quote me on that sql! But that's the general idea!

Edit:
Just re-read your question, you could easily use GROUP BY user_id to get a list of posts liked by one user!

;) have fun.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just wondering what advantage this approach has over using the post meta and user meta tables?

Comment: None, it's just what I would do.

Comment: I'm thinking of going down the custom table route but need to understand why it will be better to do so. There must be pros and cons to each approach. I'm not really asking how to set up the custom table, more why. What's the advantage? what's the pros and what's the cons etc

Comment: Pros: 
You code it yourself, you know what's going on. Great if this is a small project, you'd have full control and flexibility over the functionality (I find wordpress to be limiting and bloated) you could easily derive new functions using the data, 'most liked' 'recently liked' 'liked by x user' etc. 

Cons:
Inconsistent with wordpress, may be unclear what's going on to other programmers working on this project. Might be difficult to implement based on your current configuration.